# How to identify tracts that share a boundary or node?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, spatial-join

[image]I'm trying to identify the tracts (from a selection of 1,198 tracts) that share either a boundary or a node to maximize the total number of tracts (statewide) that meet this criteria.

The output should show a swatch of tracts stitched together by a line segment or a corner to form a contiguous run across the state (with no isolated tracts like the tract marked with a red "X" in the attached screenshot).

I've read the Polygon Neighbors tool will achieve this.  However, only first order contiguity is examined in Polygon Neighbors.

I believe this means the output may include a set of tracts that neighbor EACH OTHER but are disconnected from the rest of the tracts.  I need all tracts to be connected by a series of nodes or boundaries across the ENTIRE STATE to represent a continuous run of tracts connected statewide.

Suggestions for how to achieve my goal? I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question and include some images to explain what you want, not everyone knows what a "swatch of tracts" are?

Comment: @Hornbydd thanks for the feedback, I added a pic and some clarifying text. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

An untested workflow could be this:

1. Dissolve all polygons, You'll need to play around with allowing multi-parts I think?
2. Union the results of #1 with source data.
3. Results would be many source polygons take on the ID of the dissolve polygon ID. Your red cross example would have 1 entry. Those could be identified by a simple summary tool.